# Unable to access ElasticSearch on AWS

Tags: powershell, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am trying to use curl in powershell to access elasticsearch on an AWS instance, with no luck.

I can access the instance using putty with no problems, and can successfully run a health check on elasticsearch using `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/health?v'`. I've added a rule to the AWS security group to allow TCP requests to port 9200 from my IP, and have added the following lines to the elasticsearch.yml file:

```
http.enabled : true
http.cors.enabled : true
http.cors.allow-origin : "*"
```

I've checked ip tables, and it looks as though nothing is wrong there:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:wap-wsp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:wap-wsp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've tried sending a request from my windows machine using powershell, here's the request and error:

```
curl '*{awsPublicIP}*:9200/_cat/health?v'
curl : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ curl '*{awsPublicIP}*:9200/_cat/health?v'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I've also tried this in chrome, which resulted in a "connection refused" error:

```
http://*{AWSPublicIP}*:9200/_cat/health?v
```

I did create a .pem file whilst spinning up the instance for ssh connections, would I have to include it somehow? where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to `*{AWSPublicIP}*:9200` from your machine using a more low-lever tcp client, like netcat or telnet?

Comment: Have you checked your elasticsearch configuration to make sure that it binds to the correct network interface? You can check `netstat -np | grep 9200` to see if ES is bound to localhost only.

Comment: This seems to be a network connectivity rather than a programming problem. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) is a more suitable place for questions like that.

Comment: Just wondering, do you have security groups enabled? if so, do you have 9200 set to be accessible publicly?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments,I'v only just got a chance to revisit this. Ive created a security group which allows traffic to all tcp and udp ports from all origins, and this allows requests to port 80 (which returns the standard apache holding page). This is effective, because when I remove these rules access to port 80 is denied. I'm thinking this is an elasticsearch issue, but I'm definitely stumped!

Comment: netstat -np | grep 9200 returns nothing, should it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, ES only listens to the loopback interface.
Please read this article from ES documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html

I had the same problem and i solved it by editing the elasticsearch.yml file.
Just uncomment the line with "network.host" and change it to : 
network.host: `_eth0_`

When eth0 is your desired NIC you want to use for connections to ES.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a firewall on the OS level and not the security group.  did you check if the firewall is turned off?  what OS are you running?  if CentOS 7, firewall is enabled by default and therefore you will have this issue.

also, try to test on your elasticsearch.yml file by changing the host to 0.0.0.0

if you are using CentOS `systemctl stop firewalld`